# Trouble aligning flex columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having issues trying to align these 2 divs (`background` and `home-card`). I changed the html nesting but I can't find the right way to make them stack on top of each other (`home-card` under `background` div).

I want the `home-card` to sit under `background`, both filling the remaining viewport.

`flex-direction: column` has no effect and I feel a bit lost to be honest. It is my first time using flexbox from scratch even though I've read about it, I still have troubles when practicing.

As you can see on fullscreen snippet run, these 2 divs are next to each other. I guess `flex-grow` is causing me layout issues, but I couldn't find a better way to make the `background` div fill the whole remaining space.

Any help is appriciated. Sorry for posting the whole code but I had to provide you the right context.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:00,500,600,700|Open+Sans:400,400i,600);
@import url(https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/et-line@1.0.1/style.css);

/* Global Tweaks */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: 0
}

body {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #777;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    font-weight: 400;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif
}

.page-container {
    display: flex;
}

.main-menu, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #212121;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}

a:focus, a:hover, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0
}
/* Global Tweaks */

/* Side Menu*/
a:active {
    background-color: #333;
}

.logo {
    padding-top: 25%;
}

nav {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 25vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;  
}  

nav ul li a:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
}

nav ul li:first-child a::before {
    display: none
}

.main-menu {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

.main-menu li {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
  }

nav ul li a i {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    color: #838383;
    font-size: 2em;
}

a[href^="#"] {
    font-size: 1.05em;
    color: #212121;

}
/* Side Menu*/


/* Home Card */
section.author h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #222;
}

/* div.home-card {
    background: url(/img/final.svg) no-repeat;
    flex-grow: 1;
} */

div.background {
    background: url(/img/final.svg) no-repeat;
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color:  crimson;
}

div.home-card {
    display: flex;
}

.author {
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

.author h3 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
    body {
        background-size: auto 100vh;
    }
}
/* Home Card */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Portofoliu</title>

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main-mobile.css" media="print"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css">
    
    <!--Favicon-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    
    <!-- Responsive -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/respond.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <main class="page-container">
        <!-- Side Menu -->
        <nav>
            <ul class="main-menu">
                <li class="home active"><a class="logo" href="#home"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#cine-sunt"><i class="icon-profile-male"></i>Cine sunt</a></li>
                <li><a href="#proiecte"><i class="icon-briefcase"></i>Proiecte</a></li>
                <li><a href="#servicii"><i class="icon-adjustments"></i>Servicii</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact"><i class="icon-envelope"></i>Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- Side Menu -->

        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="background"></div>
        <div class="home-card">
            <section class="author">
                <h3>My name</h3>
            </section>
        </div>
        <!-- Content -->
    </main>
</body>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just put your background and card in a separate div you can get the desired effect.

```
<!-- Content -->
<div class="content">
    <div class="background"></div>
    <div class="home-card">
        <section class="author">
            <h3>My name</h3>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Content -->
```

CSS:

```
.content{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```